# Custom ListView adapter. Hide specific values. Android

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

I have some troubles with custom `ListView` adapter.
I send request to a web-site, which gives me xml with some data. Then I parse xml and put recieved data into `ListView` with help of class which extends `BaseAdapter`. But sometimes there are too many data for my request, so the best way is to ask from web site not all data, but range of values, and then put them into ArrayList on client.

When user pressed Forward button, new values are recieved from site and are put into ArrayList, then user pressed Backward button, so in this case is no necessity to make request to web site, because data already stored in ArrayList.

I use `startIndex` and `endIndex` variables to navigate between loaded data and when asking from web server new data. I tried to set which values should be shown in `View getView()` method of my adapter, but in this case my application crashes. Here is code. How can I load only specific data in my `ListView`.

Thanks all!

```
@Override 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    // I tried to add only specific values, here my app crashes
    if (position < startIndex || position > endIndex) return null; 
    View view = convertView; 
    if (view == null){ 
        view = this.lInflater.inflate(R.layout.book_item,parent,false); 
    } 

    Book b = getBook(position); 
    TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.authorName); 
    tv.setText(b.author); 

    tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bookName); 
    tv.setText(b.name); 


    CheckBox chBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.basketChk); 
    chBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this); 

    chBox.setTag(position); 
    chBox.setChecked(b.getStatus()); 
    return view; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to add new data to list upon retrieving cached data, you can do this by adding/removing/updating data in you collection that being used in your adapter. and call `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` which reloads the adapter into your list.

Comment: Thanks, Warlock. I'll try this method!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your requirement is:
You will 1st fetch specific set of data from site based on some range and show it to user. When user click on forward you will check if you data for that range if not fetch from web and display it, and when user clicks back show previous data.

With this understanding I propose following solution:
1. Maintain a HashMap with range as key and ArrayList of data from website for that range as value.
2. Now use this HashMap to check whether data for the range is available or not. If not fetch it from we and add it to HashMap and use it.
3. While creating adapter for ListView, create new ArrayList and pass the same as source. 
4. Now based on whether you have data forthe given range in HashMap or you fetch it from web  and add it HashMap, clear the ArrayList passed in the adapter and add all the new data and call notifyDataChange on adater.

I hope steps are clear and helpful.

Comment: And one more question: every item in ListView has check box. When user clicks checkbox, item is added into orders. I have class Book with boolean field inOrders. So Book-items are stored in HashMap. Their cached copies from a specifc range are stored in ArrayList. But if I'll have both HashMap and ArrayList I need  manually check if item in ArrayList is in orders, I need to set it added to orders in HashMap too? Thanks!

Comment: So what I understand here is that Book is the object that will be stored in ArrayList. Book is having a boolean field to indicate if inOrders. So one way is to create additional ArrayList which will hold the list of Books in order i.e. on checkBox check and uncheck event can add/remove Book from this new ArrayList of Book InOrders.

Comment: I am sorry for my confusable explaination. Thanks for help. I'll try this solution.